# Duplicated metrics using prometheus federation

Tags: prometheus

**What happened?**

The duplicated metrics appear on main prometheus server:

```
namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel{cluster="sample-eks", job="federate", namespace="cert-manager", pod="cert-manager-848f547974-xkg8j", prometheus="monitoring/k8s", prometheus_replica="prometheus-k8s-0", workload="cert-manager", workload_type="deployment"}
```

```
namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel{cluster="sample-eks", namespace="cert-manager", pod="cert-manager-848f547974-xkg8j", workload="cert-manager", workload_type="deployment"}
```

The difference is additional `job`,`prometheus` and `prometheus_replica`  labels.

**Did you expect to see some different?**

No duplicated metrics.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)**:

Install two kube-prometheus stacks on different clusters:

- one main
- one child

The main cluster will get the data from the child cluster using /federate endpoint.

Federation config:

```yaml
- job_name: 'federate'
  scrape_interval: 15s
  honor_labels: true
  metrics_path: '/federate'
  params:
    'match[]':
      - '{job=~".*"}'      
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - 'prometheus-sample.dev.xyz.com'
```

**Environment**

I use last git tag of kube-prometheus repo on AWS EKS 1.21.

- Prometheus Logs:

```
level=warn ts=2021-10-01T15:04:21.300Z caller=scrape.go:1399 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=federate target="http://prometheus-sample.dev.sample.com:80/federate?match%5B%5D=%7Bjob%3D~%22.%2A%22%7D" msg="Error on ingesting samples with different value but same timestamp" num_dropped=20
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option here is to deploy all prometheus servers with the option `replicaExternalLabelName: ""`

More info here:

https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/api.md#prometheusspec

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this achieves deduplication?

Comment: @dpwr From the documentation: External label will not be added when value is set to empty string.

There is no duplication if there is no extra label.